# How to align within a grid in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, alignment, grids

I have a group of icons which I would like to display in an organised grid. I would like to align them so that each icon is centred inside the square and evenly spaced.

Currently, I'm using **Arrange** > **Make Grid** and I'm getting the output on the right of the image below. What I would like to achieve is on the left. Is this possible within Sketch?

[image]

Comment: You could put the star in the middle of  a rectangle with no stroke or fill (an invisible rectangle), and group the two. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Found a plugin to solve my problem: https://sketchicons.com/ - not exactly what I wanted, but sorted my issue in this use case!